# ASP.Net dual OWIN authentication - how to prevent redirect to AzureAD-login for non-AD-users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

We have a `.NET 4.7.2 MVC` website in which we've implemented dual `authentication - against AzureAD using OpenIdConnect` and default application-cookie-authentication for non-AD-users.

AD-users are redirected to Microsoft login and we have a custom `login page` for the `non-AD-users.`

Our problem is that when we log in a user in our custom login page using `AuthenticationManager.SignIn`, the user is redirected to the `Microsoft login` anyway.

I've managed to fix this by adding the following to the RedirectToIdentityProvider-func in the OpenIdConnect-configuration in Startup.cs:

```
if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("login"))
{
    context.HandleResponse();
}
```

But this seems like an ugly hack. What is the proper way of handling this problem?

Comment: It should only redirect there when it gets an authorization challenge that is not met by the current thread identity.  Check whether, at the point it's redirecting, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true (it will probably also be in `HttpContext.User`), and that the user's identity reflected there satisfies the authorization demands of the code being called.  E.g. if `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is a `ClaimsPrincipal`, check that the user has the required Claims.

Comment: When I tried putting a breakpoint in the RedirectToIdentityProvider to check your suggestions, for some reason it's no longer hit, which makes no sense to me, as I was unable to get it working until I added the hack I mentioned in the OP. Which I assume means that it's now working as it should have in the first place, but I can't understand what could be different...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem adding the following line on OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions:

```
AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
```

Reference:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/300